# Messy mesh with internal vertices/faces

Tags: meshlab

Good afternoon Stack Overflow,

I am very new to meshlab. I've created some geometry with 3D points and have used the Alpha Shape filter to generate a 3D object (this is only way I could get it to work). It 'looks' quite good from the outside, however has a whopping 4 million faces and 300, 000 vertices which makes it impossible to work with outside of meshlab (I am hardware limited at the moment). Looking closely it seems many have been generated inside the geometry ([see cross section here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmj1h.png))

I would like to either:

A. Remove them and leave only a surface (if possible)

B. Create a new surface bounded by the current 3-D geometry without the internal errata (if possible)

I have tried a few different steps by google search and you tube but can not figure this one out. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For a cube (?), should probably be _far less_ faces/vertices..

Comment: It is not a cube - it's a shape based on a function (discretized, plotted and used alpha complex to generate the shape). The problem is there all the face internal to the mesh (see picture).